# Seeking open source geospatial viewer of attachments stored in file geodatabase?

Tags: file-geodatabase, software-recommendations, open-source-gis, attachments, viewer

I have a file geodatabase that contains imagery and photo attachments linked to each record of a feature class.

I am looking for a non-proprietary solution that allows a user without Esri to view these attachments.

I do not have ArcGIS Publisher, hence the question.

Comment: Are the images *inside* the FGDB, or just in a URL in a text field?  There is no solution for accessing raster data stored in file geodatabase outside  of ArcObjects.

Comment: Thanks, Vince. They are indeed inside the geodatabase. The attribute for each record links to a numbered JPEG attachment associated with it. No hyperlinked URL.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Vince:

> There is no solution for accessing raster data stored in file
>   geodatabase outside of ArcObjects.

Attachments are implemented as a relationship class that provides a many-to-many relate whereby a feature can have many raster data items attached to it, and a raster data item can be attached to more than one feature.